# How to select the element(s) which has the class name start with more than once or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In application, I am adding a class name `userNote` to the element. `userNote` will have the `numbers` as post fixed like this: `userNote1`

there is a chance that, user can select the same element multiple times. so, i would like to know the element has the multiple `class` names which is start with same pattern, for me `userNote'.

i can filter like this:

```
$('body').find('*').filter(function () {
    return this.className.match(/\buserNote/);
//it returns the value, but i don't know how many class name it has!
    });
```

But i require the `elements` with multiple `class` names with same stat name only if it has.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L9v2r9g7/)

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to split the `className` on spaces and then loop the result, looking for elements where you get more than one entry in the array starting with your string.

```
// Start out with a set of elements that have "userNote" anywhere
// in the class, then filter based on the more detailed criteria
var matches = $('[class*=userNote]').filter(function () {
    return this.className.split(' ').reduce(function(p, c) {
        return c.substring(0, 8) === "userNote" ? p + 1 : p;
    }, 0) > 1;
});
```

Now, `matches` contains a set of elements that have more than one class starting with `userNote`.

(That uses the ES5 feature `Array#reduce`, but it can be polyfilled for older browsers, or you can just use a simple `for` loop instead.)

Example:

```js
// Start out with a set of elements that have "userNote" anywhere
// in the class, then filter based on the more detailed criteria
var matches = $('[class*=userNote]').filter(function () {
  return this.className.split(' ').reduce(function(p, c) {
    return c.substring(0, 8) === "userNote" ? p + 1 : p;
  }, 0) > 1;
});

// Show results
$("<p>Text of matching elements:<br>" + matches.map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get().join("<br>") + "</p>").appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<div class="userNote">one</div>
<div class="userNote userNote2">two</div>
<div class="userNote userNote2 userNote3">three</div>
<div class="foo">none</div>
<div class="foo userNote userNote2 userNote3 userNote4 bar">four and other classes</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great solution. Bravo (+1)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder :  How can i get the length of the class.. instead getting the element..? http://jsfiddle.net/L9v2r9g7/4/

Comment: @3gwebtrain: What do you mean by "the length of the class"?

Answer (score -1):

try the below selector

```
$("p[class*=userNote]").css('color', 'blue');
```

ref : http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Answer (score -1):

Try this,
it will select all elements with *userNote* and having highlight class

```
$('body').find('[class*=userNote].highlight').length
```

I hope this is exactly what you need